# Passing Series with dtype= 'category' as categories for Pandas Categorical function

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

when I run this code I get the following error :

```
import pandas as pd

car_colors = pd.Series(['Blue', 'Red', 'Green'],
           dtype='category')

car_data = pd.Categorical(['Yellow', 'Green', 'Red', 'Blue','Purple'],
                              categories= car_colors, ordered=False)
print car_colors
s = pd.Series(car_data)
s
```

> ValueError: object **array** method not producing an array

But the funny thing is, when I remove the `dtype = 'category'`, the code works fine.

So in short, the categorical function is accepting series but not with `dtype = 'category'`

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I guess it doesn't make sense to re-make a categorical when the data already has dtype of category so it's a bug in some sense but also a little weird to want to do it this way

Comment: If you explicitly passed just the categories then it works: `car_data = pd.Categorical(['Yellow', 'Green', 'Red', 'Blue','Purple'],
                              categories= car_colors.cat.categories, ordered=False)`

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly my doubt. We can pass lists and series as categories but not categories themselves. Thanks for clearing that up EdChum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like need add `tolist` to `categories` in [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Categorical.html):

```
car_colors = pd.Series(['Blue', 'Red', 'Green'],
           dtype='category')

car_data = pd.Categorical(['Yellow', 'Green', 'Red', 'Blue','Purple'],
                              categories = car_colors.tolist(), ordered=False)

s = pd.Series(car_data)
print (s)

0      NaN
1    Green
2      Red
3     Blue
4      NaN
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [Blue, Red, Green]
```

Another solution from [EdChum's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39467885/passing-series-with-dtype-category-as-categories-for-pandas-categorical-funct/39467943#comment66255855_39467885) is use [`cat.categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.categories.html):

```
car_data = pd.Categorical(['Yellow', 'Green', 'Red', 'Blue','Purple'],
                              categories = car_colors.cat.categories, ordered=False)
s = pd.Series(car_data)
print (s)
0      NaN
1    Green
2      Red
3     Blue
4      NaN
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [Blue, Green, Red]
```